# How to emulate Windows screen timeout in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I want to emulate Windows timeout function that only starts once there are no activities of the keyboard and mouse in Tkinter. Lets says if the keyboards are not pressed, the window will destroy after 10 seconds, but every time the keyboards are pressed, the timer will be delayed for additional 5 seconds.

Example:

```
app = Tk()

time = 10000
shutdown = app.destroy()
app.after(time, shutdown)

if button == pressed:
   time+ 5000
```

However I was told .after in Tkinter cannot do this, and I indeed tried, the time will not change from 10000, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just update the `time` variable to alter the already scheduled `after` task.  You need to cancel (using `after_cancel()` on the task ID returned by `after()`) the scheduled task and reschedule a new `after` task.

However, it is more easily to do it using *count down* concept:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

timeout = 10000
delay = 100 # check count down every 100ms (adjust it to what you like)

def countdown():
    global timeout
    if timeout:
        print(timeout)
        root.after(delay, countdown)
        timeout -= delay
    else:
        print('timed out')
        root.destroy()

def extend_timeout(event):
    global timeout
    timeout += 5000

root.bind('<Key>', extend_timeout) # extend timeout by pressing any key

countdown() # start the count down
root.mainloop()
```